# How to edit EditText and TextView in UI simultaneously

Tags: android, multithreading, textview, android-edittext

I'm implementing a simple chatting application which has a TextView for text messages and a EditText for input.
I update my TextView by following method:

```
    private void addChatContent(String authorName, String content){
    final String newLine = authorName+" : "+content+"\n";
    chat_content.append(newLine);
    scroll.post(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            scroll.smoothScrollTo(0, chat_content.getBottom()+5000);
        }
    });
}
```

A problem I'm facing is: when there are new incoming messages, UI thread will be busy for refreshing the TextView. It makes my EditText become lag, I can hardly edit my input.
I can not refresh the TextView with another thread, right?
So what should I do to overcome this limitation?
Could somebody give me some light? Thanks in advance.

Comment: lag on real phone or emulator?

Comment: create a text watcher for editext, and update your textview after text changed method in text watcher.

Comment: Post the handler code that calls to `addChatContent` for more clear guidance.

Comment: Thank you guys! I am running on emulator and call the addChatContent method in a broadcastReceiver's onReceive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, and unfortunately, there is only one thread dedicated to the UI.  If you are updating the TextView there is no way you can simultaneously have a lag-free experience with the EditText.  You already know this, but I fear some people answering this question may not, so [here's a reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html):

> The system does not create a separate thread for each instance of a
>   component. All components that run in the same process are
>   instantiated in the UI thread, and system calls to each component are
>   dispatched from that thread. Consequently, methods that respond to
>   system callbacks (such as onKeyDown() to report user actions or a
>   lifecycle callback method) always run in the UI thread of the process
>
> ...
>
> When your app performs intensive work in response to user interaction,
>   this single thread model can yield poor performance unless you
>   implement your application properly. Specifically, if everything is
>   happening in the UI thread, performing long operations such as network
>   access or database queries will block the whole UI. When the thread is
>   blocked, no events can be dispatched, including drawing events.
>
> ...
>
> Additionally, the Andoid UI toolkit is not thread-safe. So, you must
>   not manipulate your UI from a worker thread—you must do all
>   manipulation to your user interface from the UI thread. Thus, there
>   are simply two rules to Android's single thread model:
>
> Do not block the UI thread
>   Do not access the Android UI toolkit from outside the UI thread

Hence, the answer is quite clear: don't do this. Why does the Textview have to be absolutely, 100% up to date, as the user is updating the EditText field? Why are you scrolling all the way to the bottom; maybe you can get away with deleting most of the contents of the TextView and, when the user scrolls, dynamically re-adding content to it?

IMO you should focus on reducing the amount of work you need to do on the TextView.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion :D
May I ask how to detect if a user is editing EditText or not?
Also how to re-adding content as you said.
Maybe some hints or informations for me? Many thanks.

Comment: RE: listening for EditText changes. You want to add a listener object using addTextChangedListener() on EditText, and the object type is usually TextWatcher. Google for both those terms, or ask a new question; to be honest I've never done this so others may have better answer.

In general, when it comes to performance my advice is to log everything using Log.d() calls and figure out, beyond a doubt, what is actually causing the delay, and then go after the biggest causes of the delay. Good luck!